# Deprecated: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in

Tags: php

Hi there anyone who can give me an hand with this thanks

```
  public function get_statement($t, &$contents)
{
   
    // Locate the statement
    $tag_length = strlen($t['b']);
    $fpos = strpos($contents, $t['b']) + $tag_length;
    $lpos = strpos($contents, $t['e']);
    $length = $lpos - $fpos;

    // Extract & return the statement
    return substr($contents, $fpos, $length);
}
```

giving error: Deprecated: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in

Comment: You should define what `$t` contains.

Comment: ^ This, plus you should state what you are trying to archieve. There's your snippet that gives errors but we neither know your data nor your desired input vs output.

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked:

```php
    public function get_statement($t, &$contents)
    {
        // Locate the statement
        $tag_length = strlen($t['b']);
        if (!empty($t['b'])) {
            $fpos = strpos($contents, (string)$t['b']) + $tag_length;
        }
        if (!empty($t['e'])) {
            $lpos = strpos($contents, (string)$t['e']);
        }
        $length = $lpos - $fpos;
        // Extract & return the statement
        return substr($contents, $fpos, $length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to the stackoverflow!

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.deprecated.php):

> Passing a non-string needle to string search functions is deprecated.

So, starting from `php 7.3` when you calling `strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset)` you need to be sure that the second parameter `$needle` is a `string`.

In most cases you can just cast it to the string like this `strpos($haystack, (string)$needle, $offset)`

Coming back to your codesample, try to fix it this way:

```php
public function get_statement($t, &$contents)
{
   
    // Locate the statement
    $tag_length = strlen($t['b']);
    $fpos = strpos($contents, (string)$t['b']) + $tag_length;
    $lpos = strpos($contents, (string)$t['e']);
    $length = $lpos - $fpos;

    // Extract & return the statement
    return substr($contents, $fpos, $length);
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and in return gotten Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in and thanks for your help :)

Comment: That means that sometimes you got `null` or `false` here. Like if you parsing something, maybe script doesn't find what it should be and passing the `false` value to the `get_statement` function. So the problem not within this function.

Comment: I didn't get the difference with my answer. If there is an difference - post your code as answer, not as comment. If there is no difference - than you select my answer as correct for the future users.

Comment: Ok, I found, you check for `if (!empty($t['b']) { }`